# Умер SSD или проблема в другом?

Tags: железо, ssd, macbook

вчера случилось несчастье.
мой макбук про 2013 late завис после 7 лет безупречной работы.
использовал его как стационарный, не таскал с собой, перезагружал раз в год, на ночь в спящий.

После зависания включил его, показался экран загрузки windows и завис.
Загрузившись с флешки проверил битые сектора ssd, прога первые 8 секунд показывала что все норм а затем пошли все битые, и диск стал нечитаемым.

По логике я так понял что при чтении диска он дает считать с себя первые несколько секунд, экран загрузки, F8 (у меня винда тоже), выбрать вариант загрузки, но после этого становится нечитаемым.

при повторной проверке диск вообще не видит, до перезагрузки. после снова дает считать с себя несколько секунд и отваливается.

Это значит умер ssd или может его контроллер? что вероятнее?

Comment: отваливается контроллер. у меня были 2 таких от SP - 2 раза перепаивали контроллер, потом поменял по гарантии на интел

Comment: подскажешь какой контроллер закупить? и как его загуглить вообще?

Comment: я не разбираюсь: беру интел где надо понадежней, где сп. сп поменять можно через раз 5 лет - они дешевые